# ActionBarCompat navigateUpFromSameTask crash on gingerbread

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-actionbar-compat

I'm trying to implement ActionBarCompat in an activity, but when I try to go back from to the main activity (which also uses ABP) by clicking the "up" button on the action bar (the one left of the app icon) the app crashes, this only happens on gingerbread, it works perfectly fine on  v4.0+.

My logcat says there's something wrong with this line of code

```
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

I'm using these in the onCreate() method

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you provide the parent Activity in the Manifest using the `<meta-data>` tag?  EX: `<meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />`

Comment: @jacobhyphenated Yes, as I said the app is working perfectly fine on v4.0+, this issue is only occurring in older android versions.

Comment: That is why I asked. The newer versions use the `android:parentActivityName` value in the manifest. Gingerbread needs the `<meta-data>` for compatibility.